# Java constructor - optional argument in a subclass constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, subclass, superclass

The overall system here is a sort of library. I have a superclass called `Person`, with two constructors: one that takes a first and last name as separate Strings, and another that takes those parameters as well as an ArrayList for middle names - the idea being that some people have no middle name. In a subclass called `Member`, I want to have the option of creating a member object with or without middle names, by passing an empty ArrayList. My first thought was something like this:

```java
if (middleNames.size() == 0) {
    super(firstName, lastName);
} else {
    super(firstName, middleNames, lastName);
}
```

But I have now realised that the `super()` constructor has to be the first statement in the subclass constructor. Hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do here - is there a good way to do it without writing two constructors in the Member class? There are several lines of code that I'd rather not repeat.

Comment: Whatever the lines of code you don't want to repeat, can you just put it in a method in the Person class?

Comment: I don't see a real reason of doing like this. Do your super class constructors do different things? I mean, what if `Person` would have a single constructor only that would check whether the `middleNames` argument is empty or not, and then do certain things itself, so that any subclasses would not even bother doing the same thing?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha would this be acceptable for the constructor? To clarify - the lines of code comprise the rest of the constructor.

Comment: @fluffy Good idea - I didn't think of that. I will see if I can implement it.

Comment: Also, the `Person` constructor would probably better accept `Collection` instead of `ArrayList` (for design reasons), and check with `isEmpty()` instead of `size() == 0` (for performance reasons).

Comment: Person(sfn,ln) and Member(fn,ln,String...mn)  what am i missing here.

Comment: Names are very tricky. What about "The artist formerly known as an unpronounceable symbol?" (Look up Prince if this confuses you.) I use a first initial and a middle name. The surname comes first in some societies. In my experience, just a single string for the name is best.

Comment: @fluffy - since the order of the (middle) names is important not just any `Collection` will do, it has to be one that defines/maintains order; `List` would be the usual choice. Also, Donagh, per NomadMaker's comment, see "Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names" https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/

Comment: @StephenP Yes, that makes sense. I was mostly thinking of the least required interface for that where even `Iterable` might be suitable, but yes a more concrete `List` seems to be a better choice.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help - I'm pretty new to java and this is part of an assignment for my course. We were told to include separate data members for first and last names. (Also, please don't change my post to American spelling. It does not make it more readable and I'm not from North America. Thanks.)

Answer (score 0):

You could construct `Member` instances via a static factory method instead of constructor.

```
class Member extends Person {
    static Member create(String firstName, List<String> middleNames, String lastName) {
        if (middleNames.isEmpty()) {
            return new Member(firstName, lastName);
        }
        return new Member(firstName, middleNames, lastName);
    }

    private Member(String firstName, String lastName) {
        super(firstName, lastName);
    }

    private Member(String firstName, List<String> middleNames, String lastName) {
        super(firstName, middleNames, lastName);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this concept (and the brief specifically tells us to use a constructor) but I will look into it - thanks!